# Issues getting PHP shuffle to output results

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, shuffle

I'm attempting to shuffle the users that I have in my database and then output the first and last name of those results. I have PHP error coding in this file and it is not throwing any errors. Just nothing is outputting not even..

`if ($shuffle_firstname == true) {
                echo $shuffle_firstname . $shuffle_lastname;
            } else {
                echo "No users have been registered yet.";
            }`

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$shuffle_run = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group`= 3");
$shuffle_numrows = mysqli_num_rows($shuffle_run);
if( $shuffle_numrows > 0) {
    while($shuffle_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($shuffle_run)){
        $shuffle_id = $shuffle_row['id'];
        $shuffle_firstname = $suffle_row['firstname'];
        $shuffle_lastname = $shuffle_row['lastname'];
        $shuffle_username = $shuffle_row['username'];
        $shuffle_email = $shuffle_row['email'];

        if ($shuffle_firstname == true) {
            echo $shuffle_firstname . $shuffle_lastname;
        } else {
            echo "No users have been registered yet.";
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['shuffle']))  {
    $shuffle_row = array();
    shuffle($shuffle_row);
    foreach ($shuffle_row as $shuffle) {
        echo $shuffle_firstname . " " . $shuffle_lastname;
    }
}

?>
<input type="submit" value="Shuffle" name="shuffle">
```

Comment: why not use "ORDER BY RAND()" in your mysql statement?

Comment: `$shuffle_firstname = $suffle_row['firstname'];` you misspelled the second `shuffle` word

Comment: Because I will be using the results from this and making a submit button to insert the results into another db table.

Comment: The misspelled word still didn't cause any results to output. Thanks for that catch though.

Comment: If you have got blank page this is probably because error reporting is off. What is the output when you enable error reporting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: I already have error reporting added in and my page is not displaying any errors for this.

Comment: have you tried using `var_dump()` on several vars to see where could be the problem ?

Comment: I changed some values in my db, as for some reason there were not any group#'s as 3. So now the line I mentioned is outputting that data, but still the shuffle isn't working.

Comment: The problem may be that you are rewriting values of `$shuffle_id`,`$shuffle_firstname`,`$shuffle_lastname`,`$shuffle_username`,`$shuffle_email` during each loop. I guess that's why the program knows only one value associated to these vars and can't shuffle with several values.I may be wrong, I think I misunderstood what you're trying to do

Comment: I'm wanting to carry forward the name, last name, email, etc so I can insert this into another db table after I shuffle it.

Comment: @Paul Do you want to shuffle users or informations you have (like an user's firstname with another user's last name) ?

Comment: @tektiv I want to shuffle the users.

Comment: `$shuffle_firstname == true`? If it's a string, then you shouldn't be comparing to true. maybe `$shuffle_firstname != ''`, or `strlen($shuffle_firstname) > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your results with an empty array, then you use `shuffle` on an empty array, then you're looping the empty array using `foreach`. I've cleaned up the code, could you try this?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `group` = 3");

echo 'Normal results: <br>';
$array = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[] = $row;
    echo $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '<br>';
}
if (isset($_POST['shuffle'])) {
    shuffle($array);
    echo 'Shuffled results: <br>';
    foreach ($array as $result) {
        echo $result['firstname'] . ' ' . $result['lastname'] . '<br>';
    }
    // echo $results[0]['firstname'] . ' ' . $results[0]['lastname']; // To display one random result
}
?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Shuffle" name="shuffle">
</form>
```

Comment: I removed that line and it didn't help.

Comment: @Paul I've updated my answer, please take a look. Haven't tested this, but this should work.

Comment: I get a bunch of errors like this... Warning: Illegal string offset 'firstname' in /home4/db/public_html/example.com/userCreator.php on line 193

Comment: Are you sure the table `users` has a column `firstname`?

Comment: Yes, it is working in my orginial code here above the shuffle code,,,`if ($shuffle_firstname == true) {
            echo $shuffle_firstname . $shuffle_lastname;
        } else {
            echo "No users have been registered yet.";
        }`

Comment: There are too many flaws in your original code. I think you are not suppose to output `"No users have been registered yet."` in your `while` statement. That could output several times `"No users have been registered yet."`. Hence the reformatting. Try to understand the code, not copy paste blindly and think it will work.

Comment: I understand the code for the most part, I just don't get why nothing is displaying.

Comment: I've updated my answer again with a simplified version, and tested the code, this works on my side.

Comment: Works great! Is there a way to make the results show up one at a time?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Say I had 10 results. Rather than all 10 shuffle results displaying at one, for them to appear one at a time.

Comment: Instead of the  `foreach` statement, just use `echo $results[0]['firstname'] . ' ' . $results[0]['lastname'];`. This will return the first row of the shuffled array. But there are many ways to accomplish this.